# Angular subscribe to a service: subscribe is not a function

Tags: angular, service, subscribe

I'm following the official Angular tutorial and I'm on this step: https://angular.io/start/data#display-the-cart-items
They show how to use a service in a component.

It's not in the tutorial but I'm trying to display the number of product present in the cart inside the TopBarComponent.

**My service cart.service.ts** :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CartService {
  items = [];

  addToCart(product) {
    this.items.push(product);
    console.log(this.items);
  }

  getItems() {
    return this.items;
  }

  clearCart() {
    this.items = [];
    return this.items;
  }

}
```

**My component top-bar.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CartService } from '../cart.service';//Set up the 

@Component({
  selector: 'app-top-bar',
  templateUrl: './top-bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./top-bar.component.css']
})
export class TopBarComponent implements OnInit {
  public numberItems = 0;
  constructor(
    private cartService: CartService,//Inject the cart service
  ) { 

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.cartService.getItems.subscribe((items) => {
       this.numberItems = items.length;
       alert(this.numberItems);
    })
  }

}
```

**My template top-bar.component.html**

```
<a [routerLink]="['/']">
  <h1>My Store</h1>
</a>

<a [routerLink]="['/cart']" class="button fancy-button">
{{numberItems}}
<i class="material-icons">shopping_cart</i>Checkout</a>
```

I got an error: this.cartService.getItems.subscribe is not a function

And of course the number of product doesn't change if I add a product in the cart.
Should I use an Obsevable on getItems ?

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: getItems is a method. You need to call it: `this.cartService.getItems()`. Note the patrentheses, to call the method. And it doesn't return an observable, so there's nothing to subscribe to. It returns an array.

Comment: Angular guide doesn't have `subscribe` function anywhere.  ngOnInit should have  `this.items = this.cartService.getItems();`

Answer (score 3):

Subscribe works with **Observables**.

Try like this:

```
getItems(): Observable<any> {
  return of(this.items);
}
```

else just do,

```
this.numberItems = this.cartService.getItems().length
```

Comment: Angular docs left rxjs out of that article to make it easy for beginners to understand Angular services.

Comment: I tried this.numberItems = this.cartService.getItems().length first but it didn't change numberItems in my template when i add a product into the array items. Probably because ngOnInit is called only one single time when the component is mounted.

Comment: You can have a method that calls the service and call it on item add. If you share stackbiltz, we can show you

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wzugnr?embed=1&file=src/app/cart.service.ts

Comment: @FélixDebon you can't initialize the number of items in ngOnInit, because as you found out, ngOnInit is only called once. Instead, you need to have a method or getter in the component that calls the service and returns the number of items. Then you call the method or getter from the template. That way, the template always gets the number of items from where it's correct: the service.

Comment: From which template ?  I have created my method  getNumberItems(){
    return this.cartService.getItems();
  }   in top_bar component  and i use {{getNumberItems()}} in the template but no result

Comment: Ok I found the solution:  getNumberItems(){
    return this.cartService.getItems().length;
  }   in the .ts and {{getNumberItems()}} in the template

Comment: @FélixDebon Great :)

Answer (score 1):

In your Service, you can add an event emitter, that will emit the length each time something added to the cart.

**In CartService**
Do like this

```
import { Injectable, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RecipesService {
  cartQty = new EventEmitter<number>();
  items = [];
  constructor() { }

 addToCart(product) {
    this.items.push(product);
    this.cartQty.emit(this.items.length);
  }

  getItems() {
    return this.items;
  }

  clearCart() {
    this.items = [];
    this.cartQty.emit(this.items.length);
    return this.items;
  }

  getCartQty() {
    return this.cartQty;
  }
}
```

In **Topbar component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RecipesService } from './app.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1>cart {{qty}}!</h1>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private recipesService:RecipesService) {};
  qty: number;
  @Input() name: string;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.recipesService.getCartQty().subscribe(res => {
      this.qty = res;
    })
  }
}
```

[Working Solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h31z3f)